# addEventListener for "offline" firing multiple times in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, event-listener

For some reason, When the application goes into offline mode the event listener is firing multiple times and how to make it fire only once.

```
  $rootScope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function (event, view) {

    $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
    var popup;

    $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        $rootScope.online = false;
        popup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
          title: 'Network Problem',
          content: 'Sorry, Please Check Your Network Connection.'
        })
      });
    }, false);
    $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
      $rootScope.$apply(function () {
        $ionicLoading.show({
          template: '<p>Loading...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>',
        });
        $rootScope.online = true;
        $state.reload();
  }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By clearing cache, event firing only once.

```
 $rootScope.$on('$ionicView.afterLeave', function (event, view) {
   $ionicHistory.clearCache();
 });
```